# How it's possible that sub instruction cause invalid pointer read?

Tags: windows, assembly, x86-64, crash-dumps

I have a crash dump with this code:

```
mov     r11,rsp
push    rdi
sub     rsp,0A0h
mov     qword ptr [rsp+30h],0FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFEh
```

It's a prologue of a function. So, `!analyze -v` says `INVALID_POINTER_READ` with instruction `sub`.
AMD instructions set says that `sub` instruction cannot produce any exceptions if argument isn't a memory pointer.

Also, `READ_ADDRESS` is `ffffffffffffffff`, but in registers window I can see that `rsp` is `12b3e0`. And this is 32-bit application in 64-bit OS.

I want to know about a possible reasons of this error and how to fix it.

UPD:

Method is std._Tree.insert(const value_type& _Val) in Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\xtree.

Compiler is cl.exe from Visual Studio 2008 installation, 32-bit, version 15.00.30729.01.

Command line:

```
 /FD /EHsc /MD /GS- /Zc:wchar_t- /Yu"stdafx.h"/W3 /WX /nologo /c /Zi /TP /wd4250 /FI -Zm200 -MP -w34100 -w34189
```

Linker is from the same source, version 9.00.30729.01.

UPD: for those who have a sceptical views on debugging 32-bit apps with 64-bit debuggers, I have ran a 32-bit version of a debugger and got the same results. So, I still think that it's `sub` instruction.

UPD: to clarify: the *application* is built for *32-bit* platform. But the **processor** and **Operation System** is **64-bit**. So, there is nothing strange that in the dump we can see 64-bit registers with 32-bit values.

Comment: DEP? Or bogus info from debugger.

Comment: You sure it's the `sub` that's failing?  Doesn't RIP like to point at the instruction after the failing one...?

Comment: David, EXCEPTION_PARAMETER1 says 0, so it's not DEP.

Comment: I think it's this instruction 'cause it's mentioned in `EXCEPTION_RECORD` as `ExceptionAddress`.

Comment: How is it possible that you are debugging a 32-bit application, and the code you are showing is 64-bit?

Comment: Don't know. Windbg maybe. I hope someone here could answer how it works when you run 32-bit apps on 64-bit systems. Also, this code is not from realtime debugging, it's from crash dump.

Comment: Did you write the program yourself or do you have access to the source code? If yes, please show us the source code also and tell us which assembler/compiler and linker you used and with which options, so that the possible error can be replicated. And any case, if there's something else in the crash dump (register values, memory dump, etc. even if it seemed trivial to you) please edit your question and include the entire crash dump in the question.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that a heap corruption error can mask itself as an invalid pointer.  If it is heap corruption, the error would have occurred before the actual code you are showing.

Comment: I could believe that it's heap corruption if it were some read data instruction and it were working with memory. If h.c. could be with instructions which don't use memory I would like to read about this more. If I got correct exception address, of course.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2010/09/29/capturing-memory-dumps-for-32-bit-processes-on-an-x64-machine.aspx

Comment: I have read that it's not important which debugger (32 or 64) I will use as for windbg on msdn as long as I have right debugging symbols installed. Also, I have no wow64 calls in call stack and 32-bit values in register, so I think I have right dump. Discussion about dumps and bitness is for another thread I think 'cause now it's not important.

Comment: Best practice is to use a 32 bit debugger to debug 32 bit processes/dumps.

Comment: If you're getting that exception on the `sub` instruction then either the documentation is wrong or there's a bug in your hardware. It's up to you to decide whether it's more likely that the failure occurred in that `sub`, or somewhere else and either the debugger is reporting the wrong information or you're interpreting the information incorrectly.

Comment: We are skeptical because `sub  rsp,0A0h` is an illegal instruction in a 32-bit process so your crash dump probably does not correspond to the correct process or the correct context

Comment: @RaymondChen, I didn't write that crash is from 32-bit platform.

Comment: Then there is definitely something wrong because `rsp` is not available in 32 bit node.

Comment: @RaymondChen, look at the new update section. And tell me what's wrong and some example of 32-bit registers in dump if application was run in 64-bit OS.

Comment: It is still strange. If it is a 32-bit application, then it should be using `esp` instead of `rsp` because `rsp` is a 64-bit register that is not available to 32-bit processes. If a program accesses `rsp` then it is not a 32-bit program. The 64-bit registers are not accessible to 32-bit processes, even if they are running on a 64-bit OS.

Comment: Perhaps you ran out of stack space.  The stack grows down which is why you see a subtract of 0xA0 from the stack pointer to create a stack frame.  A value of 0x12b3e0 looks small for a stack pointer.  Maybe the fault occurred at the "push rdi".  What is in r11?

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, the problem is either in the preceding or succeeding instruction. Your debugger or the crash generator code has an off-by-one bug, it seems.

Answer (score 2):

Something else is going on.  There is no memory read operation within that entire set of opcodes.  You only have two writes (the push and the mov).  Your alignment is fine and placing the immediate qword value -2 is being done in a region of the stack that should OK.

The bitiness of the OS and opcodes have nthing to do with this.  I use 64-bit registers all the time.  It is just like using 32-bit when everything was 16-bit.

Look someplace else.